# ER_parse_error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; Failed to enter data -Nodejs -mysql -express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I managed to display data from database next I try to add data to my database here is my code snippet >>>

```
    exports.tambahData = (req, res) => {
    var keyy = req.body.keyy;
    var valuee = req.body.valuee;
    var brand = req.body.brand;
    var productName = req.body.productName;

   connection.query(
   "INSERT INTO `keranjang` (keyy,valuee,brand,productName) VALUES(?,?,?,?,)",
   [keyy, valuee, brand, productName],
   (err, rows, fields) => {
       if (err) {
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           response.ok("successfully added ", res);
         }
       }
     );
   };
```

but i getting an error below

ERROR:**er_parse_error: you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mariadb server version for the right syntax to use near**

Any Ideas on how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

You have an additional comma (`,`) in your sql statement

```
INSERT INTO `keranjang` (keyy,valuee,brand,productName) VALUES(?,?,?,?,)
```

Try changing it to

```
INSERT INTO `keranjang` (keyy,valuee,brand,productName) VALUES(?,?,?,?)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: thanks solved, looks like I was too excited to miss it

Answer (score 0):

"INSERT INTO `keranjang` (keyy,valuee,brand,productName) VALUES(?,?,?,?,)",

Correct this line to

"INSERT INTO `keranjang` (keyy,valuee,brand,productName) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",

Comment: thanks solved, looks like I was too excited to miss it